# Parsing JSON output from API

Tags: php, json, parsing

I know this one has been asked loads of times, so mods please do not close this off as no past answers have worked and I have searched already! So I'm using the HaveIBeenPwned API which outputs what is apparently JSON like so:

```
[
 {
  "Title":"000webhost"
  ,"Name":"000webhost"
  ,"Domain":"000webhost.com"
  ,"BreachDate":"2015-03-01"
  ,"AddedDate":"2015-10-26T23:35:45Z"
  ,"PwnCount":12345678
  ,"Description":"In approximately March 2015, the free web hosting provider 000webhost suffered a major data breach that exposed over 13 million customer records. The data was sold and traded before 000webhost was alerted in October. The breach included names, email addresses and plain text passwords."
  ,"DataClasses":[
    "Email addresses"
    ,"IP addresses"
    ,"Names"
    ,"Passwords"
  ]
  ,"IsVerified":true
  ,"IsSensitive":false
  ,"LogoType":"png"
 }
]
```

That is the output if I use the following:

```
echo $output;
```

`json_decode($output)` doesn't work. Using a `foreach($output as $key)` doesn't work, it says invalid argument if I use that. I have tried a normal `for()` loop and again no joy. What is wrong with this output? How do I get at the values within it? As you should be able to tell I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode($output, true);`

Second parameter defines result data format - object (false, default) or associated array (true).

Comment: Nope am afraid I just get - Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\havei\index.php on line 27. I used what you told me to, there is some kind of an issue with it, just doesn't seem to want to output it.

Comment: So for example if I use <code>$fs = json_decode($output, true);</code> then try <code>echo $fs['Title']</code> I just get another error: Notice: Undefined index: Title in C:\xampp\htdocs\havei\index.php on line 28

Comment: Update your question with your code example, so we could answer your question

Comment: Ok, what if print_r($fs); ?

Comment: <pre><code>$file = file_get_contents('https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/foo@bar.com', false, $context);
 $fs = json_decode($file, true);
 echo $fs['Title'];</code></pre>

Comment: I think you need $fs[0]['Title']; in you case, because your json string starts with [

Comment: If I use print_r($fs); the output is:

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [Title] => 000webhost [Name] => 000webhost..... - output is over how much am allowed to type here but that is how it starts off.

Comment: Yes, try $fs[0]['Title'];

Comment: Thank you 'mnv' that worked perfectly! Finally I can get the output properly.